# Stop unwanted repetition of a div while hovering it

Tags: jquery, animation, html

Dear specialists,

I have a question. I am new to Jquery and I am trying to make use of div animation according to the example code given below. What happens is that while hovering the mouse various times in a short amount over the div the action reproduces itself and causes an usability behavior that I would like to avoid somehow. Is there a way to make the function check on the mouse behavior for example the div hovering in a given amount of time to avoid unwanted multiple activation?
I hope I explained well enough.

Thanks for your input.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#expand_smoke").hover(
         //on mouseover
          function() {
              $(this).animate({
              height: '+=125' //adds 125px
               }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
              );
           },
         //on mouseout
          function() {
              $(this).stop()
             $(this).animate({
             height: '60' //changes back to 60px
        }, 'slow'
      );
    }
  );

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just do this?

```
$("#expand_smoke").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ height: '200' }, 'slow');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ height: '60' }, 'slow');
    }
);
```

Comment: Wow. eeeeer. Well, that is...simple. And it works. I I did not even think about that beauty. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

This should work if i understood you correctly:
it starts a timeout on hover, an cancels it on mouseout, so the animation only starts if you hover it for at least 500ms.

```
var timeout = null;
$("#expand_smoke").hover(
    //on mouseover
    function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            $(this).animate({height: '+=125'}, 'slow');
        },500);
    },
    //on mouseout
    function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $(this).stop().animate({height: '60'}, 'slow'
    );
});
```

Comment: Why do you need al this? What's wrong with jQuery .stop() function?

Comment: @Bart because, as i understood the question, he doesn't want the animation to start if he just moves the mouse quickly over the element. Also he already uses stop in his code, so i thought that's not the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I hover it for as long as I like but it does not start the animation. Strange. I myself can not find a bug. Any ideas? Might interfere with something else in the code.

Comment: @MichaelSchwark yeah, i wrote setTimout instead oft setTimeout... :)

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same thing for one my projects, I recommend you the [**hoverIntent**](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin which did the job quite well for me, try it.

Comment: Sweeet, gracias! Just out of curiousity, there is really no way to achieve that within the jquery code of the function itself?

Comment: De nada! , yes of course, you could take a look at the plugin code itself, and adapt it, it's very short! http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.js